# Unable to click on any part of the UIScrollView to scroll through the images. There is only a specific porition I can click on

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimage

I've some UIImages loaded into a UIScrollView.

However, when I try to scroll through these UIImages, I can only click on a specific area in the screen.

What is the property I should look out for to expand the "clickable area"? Such that I can click on any part of the scroll view to start scroll through the images.

Is there anything to do with content size of the scroll view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that -userInteractionEnabled is NO for the views you add to your scroll view.

Update:
Set -clipsToBounds to YES and see whether the scrollview's frame is just too small and the content goes beyond the bounds of the view.

Comment: Hi. I changed the userInteraction property to NO. Still no change to the clickable area.

Comment: Did you set -clipsToBounds to NO? Maybe the scrollview's frame is too small and your content goes beyond the bounds of the view.

Comment: Hi @Fabian Kreiser, you are right. The scrollview frame is too small and the content inside is beyond the bounds of the view. Thank you for you help. After your comment I finally understood what the clipToBound really means.